# Using git lfs with S3 compatible storage

Tags: git, amazon-s3, git-lfs

we have a local TFS 2015 environment and a S3 compatible storage where we want to store large files to.

I found this: https://github.com/meltingice/git-lfs-s3

Is it possible to use it with a S3 compatible storage instead of an Amazon S3? I tried it but got stuck with the authentication and configuraton as I can't see where to specify the S3 compatible endpoint. I neither can see where the Amazon S3 endpoint is specified so I think thats hidden in the used AWS Helper libs used in this project.

So I think my scenarion is not possible, right?

Any other Ideas how to use git with S3 compatible storage? Do we have to write our own lfs api?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came across during my research:

- TFS 2015 uses the database to store large files by default when using git lfs.
- VSTS supports git lfs & offers free storage right now.
- To use a AWS S3 Storage with git lfs, there is a sample for such a batch API https://github.com/meltingice/git-lfs-s3 . This sample does not support S3 compatible storage
- To use S3 compatible storage, you must implement your own git lfs batch API which seems not to be so difficult. Your S3 Storage must support presigned URLs for this.

As my company now offers JFrog Aritfactory as a shared service, we will jump on and use git lfs on JFrog.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using TFS with LFS then the files are stored inside of TFS and not on s3 storage.